# Exit loop and start new parallel loop

Tags: powershell, loops

i have a problem understanding the right way of using the different loops or combining them.

At the moment i use the regular foreach statement to start-process each file in a specific folder.

```
$basedbs = Get-ChildItem $pBase -Filter *.qvw -Recurse | % { $_.FullName } | Sort-Object

ForEach ($basedb in $basedbs) {

Start-Process "C:\Program Files\QlikView\Qv.exe" "/r $basedb" -Wait 

}
```

That works perfect as it should only loop once and than exit.
After that i want to do the same thing with all files in two other folders. But in parallel and until a specific time.

I do not really understand how to use the foreach-object -parallel instead of the foreach in this case.

Summary:

1. Starting process for each file in folder x only once (1x)
2. Exit that loop and start the Parallel-Loop
3. Starting processes for each files in two other folders in parallel (endless)

I hope you understand and maybe have some suggestions for me to get a solution on this one.

Thanks in advance,
Dennis

Comment: Why is it important that the second loop is parallel?

Comment: You would have to use `$using:basedb` in a parallel foreach.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Actually they should just start at the same time.
At the moment i could just solve this having 3 different scripts.

Comment: @djuara sure, but _why_ should they start at the same time? What timing/synchronization issue are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm starting qlikview dashboards and reload them to get new data. That process has to be repeated all day. But some of those are needed a little more often (every 20min) that's why i seperated them from the others.
In fact i have two loops.